# How do I properly implement Django formsets with a CreateView ( Class Based View )?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

And thanks in advance for any suggestions.  I have been playing around with how to properly implement formsets with a CreateView for a couple of days and I'm stuck.  Here is my code.

My Models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,null=False,blank=False)

class Player(models.Model):
    
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,null=False,blank=False)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My View:

```
class CreateTeamView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = CreateTeamForm
    template_name = 'create_team.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateTeamView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['new_player'] = NewPlayerFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['nwe_player'] = NewPlayerFormSet()
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(CreateTeamView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):

        context = self.get_context_data()
        new_player_form = context['new_player']

        if new_player_form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            new_player_form.instance = self.object
            new_player_form.save()
            instance = form.save()
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

My Forms:

```
class CreateTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        exclude = []

NewPlayerFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Team, Player, extra=1, fields=['player_name',])
```

My HTML:

```
 <div="players>

  <div="add_players">

{{ new_player.management_form }}

{% for form in new_player %}

{{ form.id }}

{{ form.player_name }}

   </div>
 </div>
```

My form is saving one player, but when I try to update the code to save more than one player with the initial CreateView, it only recognizes the first contact.  I have overridden the BaseInlineFormset to do validation as shown below....

```
class NewPlayerFormSet(NewPlayerFormSet,BaseInlineFormSet):

        player_name = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.TextInput)

        def add_fields(self, form, index):
            super(NewPlayerFormSet,self).add_fields(form,index)
            form.fields['player_name'].required = False

        def clean(self):

            super(NewPlayerFormSet, self).clean()

            for form in self.forms:
                if form.cleaned_data.get('player_name'):
                    pass
                else:
                    form.add_error('player_name','Player Name is required.')
                    pass
```

I'm trying to get the code to save a second contact.  I have used tried various JQuery attempts....but am unclear if my problem is with JQuery or mayby my HTML templates?  That's where I'm stuck.

I tried to do something like...

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

       // Watch for the 'add player' click
       $('#add_player').click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           
           $('div.add_player:last').clone().each(function(i) {
               $(this).find('input,select').each(function(i) {

                   // Remove any existing values
                   $(this).val('');

           }).appendTo('div#players');

       });
   });
```

And while this works to duplicate the form, the players beyond number 1 are not being saved.  Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

It would appear there is a JQuery plugin for this, but I'm trying to avoid using it for a number of reasons.  Thanks again for any help to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not easy.  I spent about a week trying to piece this all together.  Here are all of the parts that I used to finally make it work.  I ultimately did wind up using jquery.formset.js from GitHub in my solution.  Hope I save someone a week.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,null=False,blank=False)

class Player(models.Model):
    
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,null=False,blank=False)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My Views.py

```
class CreateTeamView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = TeamForm
    template_name = 'create_team.html'


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        player_form = CreatePlayerFormSet()
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  player_form=player_form,
                                  ))

    def form_valid(self, form, player_form):

        self.object = form.save()
        player_form.instance = self.object
        player_form.save()

        instance = form.save()

    def form_invalid(self, form, player_form):

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  player_form=player_form,
                                  ))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        player_form = CreatePlayerFormSet(self.request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid() and player_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, player_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, player_form)
```

My Forms.py

```
class CreateTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Team
    exclude = [ ]

CreatePlayerFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Team, Player, extra=1, fields=(['player_name'])
```

My HTML Template: ( Using jquery/jquery.formset.js )

```
<script src="{% static 'jquery/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".inline.{{ player_form.prefix }}").formset({
            prefix: "{{ player_form.prefix }}",
        })
    })
</script>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="forms">

{% csrf_token %}

{{ player_form.management_form }}

{{ player_form.non_form_errors }}

{% for form in player_form %}

  {{ form.id }}

  <div class="inline {{ player_form.prefix }}">
    <div class="leftwidth22">
      <div class="width52">
        <h2 class="floatright23">Player Name - </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="rightwidth53">
        <h2 class="width70">
          {{ form.player_name }}
        </h2>
      </div>

{% endfor %}
```