# Is it possible to pass a specific value to a django formset?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

So I've been playing with Django formsets for about a week and I'm about ready to throw out Django altogether.  Just kidding.  Kinda.  :).  I have the standard inline formset implementation working finally as I documented here.  [How do I properly implement Django formsets with a CreateView ( Class Based View )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66876449/how-do-i-properly-implement-django-formsets-with-a-createview-class-based-view)  Hope it helps someone.  Now I'm trying to leverage this code by trying to pass a specific queryset to it as shown below.

```
class PlayerFormSet(PlayerFormSet,BaseInlineFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlayerFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Player.objects.filter(team_pk=20)
```

As shown above, if I hard code a value, no worries it works to populate my formset.  Although hardcoding this value is of little value to the implementation.  I have researched form_kwargs, played around with numerous implementations as shown throughout SO, about passing a value but nothing I try works other than the code above for one team obviously and I can't for the life of me figure out how to do something like:

```
class PlayerFormSet(PlayerFormSet,BaseInlineFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlayerFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Player.objects.filter(self.object.team_pk)
```

Or...

```
class PlayerFormSet(PlayerFormSet,BaseInlineFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlayerFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Player.objects.filter(self.instance.team_pk)
```

I know the pk, it can clearly be passed here in a hardcoded fashion...And I have the value accessible in my view.  I just can't figure out how to pass it to the formset to get the proper queryset.  Is this even possible?  This seems to be way more challenging than it should be.  Or of course it could be me.  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Update for more thorough analysis.

My Models....

```
class Team(models.Model):

    team_name = models.CharField(null=True) 

class Player(models.Model):

    player_name = models.CharField(null=True) 
    team_pk = models.IntegerField(null=True) 
    team = models.ForeignKey("Team",null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
PlayerFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Team, Player, extra=0, fields=['player_name',])

class PlayerFormSet(PlayerFormSet,BaseInlineFormSet):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(PlayerFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.queryset = Player.objects.filter(team_pk=20)
```

views.py

```
class UpdateTeamView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = TeamForm
    template_name = 'update_team.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UpdateTeamView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        dropdown = self.request.GET.get("dropdown", None)
        queryset = Player.objects.filter(team_pk=dropdown)
        player_form = PlayerFormSet(queryset=queryset)
        context['player_form'] = player_form
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form, player_form):

        self.object = form.save()
        player_form.instance = self.object
        player_form.save()

    def form_invalid(self, form, player_form):

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                  player_form=player_form,
                                  ))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if "cancel" in request.POST:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Team:team_main_menu'))
        else:
            self.object = None
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            player_form = PlayerFormSet(self.request.POST)
            if (form.is_valid() and player_form.is_valid()):
                return self.form_valid(form, player_form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form, player_form)
```

My Template...

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="forms">

{% csrf_token %}

    {{ player_form.management_form }}

    {{ player_form.non_form_errors }}

    {% for hidden in player_form.management_form %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for form in player_form.forms %}

      {{ form.id }}

      <div class="inline {{ player_form.prefix }}">
        <div class="leftwidth22">
          <div class="width52">
            <h2 class="floatright23">Player Name - </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="rightwidth53">
            <h2 class="width70">
              {{ form.player_name }}
            </h2>
          </div>

        {% if player_form.non_form_errors %}

          <h3 class="spacer12">
            {{ player_form.non_form_errors }}
          </h3>

        {% endif %}

        {% if form.player_name.errors %}

          <h3 class="spacer12">
            {{ form.player_name.errors }}
          </h3>

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only view using the inlineformset then you can ditch the BaseInlineFormset override and just give the queryset to the formset call in the view.

Because this is an inlineformset it can take an instance of the parent (instead of a queryset of the objects themselves).

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(UpdateTeamView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    dropdown = self.request.GET.get("dropdown", None)
    instance = Team.objects.get(pk=dropdown)
    player_form = PlayerFormSet(instance=instance)
    context['player_form'] = player_form
    return context
```

Now the get portion should work. The post and form_valid need fixing too. You don't need to check the form, as all forms will be validated by the formset. Try:

```
def form_valid(self, player_form):
        player_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def form_invalid(self, player_form):
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(player_form=player_form))

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Team:team_main_menu'))
    else:
        instance = Team.objects.get(team_pk=dropdown)
        player_form = PlayerFormSet(self.request.POST,instance=instance)
        if player_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(player_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(player_form)
```